# How to understand 'losses' in Spacy's custom NER training engine?

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language-processing, objective-functions, spacy, named-entity-recognition

From the tid-bits, I understand of neural networks (NN), the Loss function is the difference between predicted output and expected output of the NN. I am following [this tutorial](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/examples/training/train_ner.py), the losses are included at line #81 in the `nlp.update()` function.

I am getting losses in the range 300-100. How to interpret them? **What should be the ideal output of this losses variable**? I went through Spacy's documentation, but nothing much is written there about losses. Also, please let me know the links to relevant theories to understand this in general.

Comment: Just to add to the accepted answer, the specific value of the loss is meaningless, you just want it to go down during training.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A critical goal of training a neural network is to minimize the loss.  Loss is not explained for spaCy because it is a general concept for machine learning and deep learning.  Loss is not specific to spaCy and although there are some finer details I don't believe that is your inquiry.

In general, to understand loss functions, I recommend the following resources:

- [Loss and Loss Functions for Training Deep Learning Neural Networks](https://machinelearningmastery.com/loss-and-loss-functions-for-training-deep-learning-neural-networks/) by Jason Brownlee.  Jason writes some great articles and tutorials and I highly suggest reading his other articles and books.
- [Introduction to Loss Functions](https://algorithmia.com/blog/introduction-to-loss-functions)
- [Loss Functions in Machine Learning for Beginners](https://medium.com/ai%C2%B3-theory-practice-business/loss-functions-in-machine-learning-for-beginners-fastai-lesson-9-homework-2-2121954f1f77) by John Kaller

If you like videos watch:

- [Loss Functions Explained](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IVVVjBSk9N0) by Siraj Raval.  Siraj has many great videos on machine learning.